# Between Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04, did Evince completely lose its settings menu?

Tags: ubuntu, pdf-reader, dark-mode, evince, ubuntu-22.04

This is my current version of evince

```bash
$ dpkg -l | grep evince
ii  evince                                                      42.3-0ubuntu2                           amd64        Document (PostScript, PDF) viewer
ii  evince-common                                               42.3-0ubuntu2                           all          Document (PostScript, PDF) viewer - common files
```

In Xubuntu 20.04, it had a settings menu that I could use to trigger Dark Mode. [This answer shows it exactly as I recall](https://askubuntu.com/a/1130537/824054). Here's their picture.

[image]

I'm now in Xubuntu 22.04 and I can see no such menu.

[image]

This leaves me stuck in Light Mode.

Where did this menu go? What is to blame? Ubuntu, Evince, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, some menus have been merged or changed. You didn't see what was right in front of you.

[image]